# Object Detection Algorithm that detects four corners of arbitrary quadrilateral, not just perpendicular rectangular

Tags: object-detection

Is there some established Object Detection algorithm that is able to detect the four corners of an arbitrary quadrilateral  (x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) as opposed to the more typical perpendicular rectangular (x,y,w,h) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV's [cv2.minAreaRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect) to detect oriented/rotated rectangular bounding boxes. Below's an example result from [OpenCV-Python-tutorials](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#b-rotated-rectangle):

[image: Using cv2.minAreaRect()]

Alternatively, you could train a supervised object detection model to output 8 co-ordinate values (x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) of the quadrilateral by training with a labeled oriented-bounding-box dataset. You could also create the bounding box labels yourself for the same by using tools such as [VGG Annotator Tool](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/via_demo.html) among others.